# relocatable schema not provoking changes in Gnome panel

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gsettings

In order to hide the main menu bar of a Gnome panel, this command should make it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.toplevel:/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ auto-hide "yes"
```

but I see no effect after executing it, the new value is there, as shown by `get`, but the menu stays, even after login out and in again.
Other changes made to the `preferences` schema take place immediately, but not those made to this relocatable schema.

I need to provoke these changes without root privileges.

Note: the same question has been sent to askubuntu forum.